# Jenkins Windows Batch Script failing to find COM object

Tags: jenkins, vbscript, installshield

I have a script that updates an Install Shield .ism file (via InstallShield Automation Interface (2015)) with a version and ProductCode.

```
Dim projFile, projVersion

'check for arguments
If Wscript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "InstallShield Version Utility" & _
        vbNewLine & "1st argument is the full path to the .ism file" & _
        vbNewLine & "2nd argument is the new version number Major.Minor.Build"
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

'get the args
projFile = WScript.Arguments(0)
projVersion = WScript.Arguments(1)

'Create the end-user automation object
Dim ISWIProject
Set ISWIProject = CreateObject("ISWiAuto22.ISWiProject"): CheckError

'Open the project specified at the command line
ISWIProject.OpenProject projFile: CheckError

'change the product code to force major upgrades
Dim guidProductCode
guidProductCode = ISWIProject.GenerateGUID
ISWIProject.ProductCode = guidProductCode

'update the version
ISWIProject.ProductVersion = projVersion

'Save and close the project
ISWIProject.SaveProject: CheckError
ISWIProject.CloseProject: CheckError

WScript.Echo "Updated guid to: " & guidProductCode & ", version to: " & projVersion

Sub CheckError()
    Dim message, errRec
    If Err = 0 Then Exit Sub
    message = Err.Source & " " & Hex(Err) & ": " & Err.Description
    WScript.Echo message
    WScript.Quit 2
End Sub
```

I call this script with

```
cscript //Nologo setInstallShieldVersion.vbs <ISMPath> <VersionNumber>
```

When I run this via a command line on the machine (with the same user as my Jenkins service), it works fine and runs the script.  However when Jenkins runs it via a Windows batch command, it gives the error

> setInstallShieldVersion.vbs(17, 1) Microsoft VBScript runtime error: File not found: 'CreateObject'

the script used to work, then I had to update Jenkins (and subsequently rolled it back when the script started failing). Maybe that's part of the issue?

I've tried dumping the environmental variables with `SET` in both instances, and all the environmental variables are the same (except some Jenkins-specific ones).  I've registered the DLL with `regsvr32` multiple times.  In both instances they are running in 32 bit processes. I've even opened up the permissions on the .dll (`ISWiAutomation22.dll`). Any other ideas on why it would work when running it one way and not the other?